# Problem with InternetOpenA (undefined reference to `___imp_InternetOpenA`

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to use a InternetOpenA, and InternetConnectA, as well as other functions defined in <wininet.h>, but I keep getting this error: "undefined reference to `___imp_InternetOpenA`".

I have tried some solutions offered across the internet, such as linking the header file into the "librarys used" field in Code::Blocks, to no avail.

I have also tried looking for the wininet.lib file, but it does not seem to exist on my computer.

Also, it is worth noting that the code in my program utilizes InternetOpen, InternetConnect, etc - the versions of these functions without A. I believe this means the code is deprecated, because I didn't find these functions in the header file.

I have replaced them with the "A" version, which shows the same error, despite the newer version being defined in the wininet.h file.

Comment: `wininet.lib` is what you need to link against, one way or another.  It mystifies me why people use Code::Blocks when Visual Studio is so much better.

Comment: Hahahaha just found out the solution - there is a file with a bunch of librarys inside the Code::Blocks, but they are in the format: "libwininet.a" "libx.a", and that is why my search wasn't working. Code::Blocks has strange peculiarities indeed.

Comment: Ah yes.  Different build chain (to VS), different library format.

Comment: BTW you can answer your own question, might help someone (and earn you some rep).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Good point.  Reopened it :)

Comment: @PaulSanders: And it has been closed again. :)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Oh well, at least it's a better dup.